# Does Spark-SQL supports Hive Select All Query with Except Columns using regex specification

Tags: regex, apache-spark, hive, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to achieve [this functionality](https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/7703/whether-hive-supports-hive-select-all-query-with-e.html) using SPARK-SQL using a pyspark wrapper.I have ran into this error

````
    pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: u"cannot resolve '```(qtr)?+.+```' 
    given input columns:
````

This is my query..Basically trying to exclude the column 'qtr'.

```
select `(qtr)?+.+` from project.table;
```

Works perfectly fine in hive/beeline using below property

```
set hive.support.quoted.identifiers=none;
```

Any help is appreciated ?

Comment: not exactly what you're asking, but if you read the table into a dataframe (`df = spark.sql("select * from project.table")`), you can use a list comprehension: `df = df.select(*[c for c in df.columns if c != "qtr"])`

Comment: ^^ the suggested list comprehension is a lot more legible than the regex incantation

Answer (score 8):

Spark allows the RegEx as a column name in `SELECT` expression. By default this behavior is disabled. To enable it we need to set the below property to `true` before running the query with RegEx columns.

```
spark.sql("SET spark.sql.parser.quotedRegexColumnNames=true").show(false)
```

After setting this property we can the select expression with regex as below.

```
spark.sql("SELECT `(.*time.*)+.+` FROM test.orders limit 2""").show(false)
```

Note: Here it allows any java valid RegEx. I have tested this solution in Spark 2.3

Comment: Here I have written the RegEx to get all the columns that have `time` string in them.